# Remote Config doesnt fetch anything

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm having an issue with Firebase's remote config, the same code works just fine in another app, but on this app i'm working on i'm barely works!! i've checked "connect your app to firebase" and "add remote config to your app" everything is OK, so i think the problem is somehow with the code, because i don't see any "fetch succeded" or "fetch failed" in logs:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRemoteConfig.fetch(0)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("firebaseconfig", "Fetch Succeeded");
                            // Once the config is successfully fetched it must be activated before newly fetched
                            // values are returned.
                            mRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("firebaseconfig", "Fetch failed");
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}, 0);
```

Any help pleeease? Thank you very much

Comment: Add a log message to verify that the run() method is actually called?